# HttpClient initialization within a static class

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm learning C#. Would it be correct to initilize an HttpClient within a static class like this?

```
public static class Network {
    static string token = "";
    static string baseAddress = "";

    static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static Network() {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Network.baseAddress);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Network.token);
    }
}
```

Also is it possible to do the initilization in one line, something like

```
static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient() {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(Network.baseAddress),
    DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Network.token)  //this does not work
};
```

Comment: remove `httpClient.` from the line it doesnt work...

Comment: Since you are learning I'm going to ask you this question to help provide a useful answer, why do you want to do that? and should this class be static?

Comment: *"Would it be correct?"* Well sure, why not. This is an opinion-based question though. It's correct to have a static `HttpClient` and if you want it in a static class, so be it. I'd suggest `new`ing up the object in the constructor though, otherwise you're splitting the initialisation code into two places.

Comment: @JamieRees, I want to do that because it is recommended to make one instance of a client within the app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-2.1 and I want to keep all network things within one place

Comment: @yaugenka I'd recommend looking at `IHttpClientFactory` as there are many issues with having a static `HttpClient` that the factory takes care of.

Comment: @JamieRees, do you mean that it is not good doing the way they suggest in the docs? Can you please give an example why?

Comment: @yaugenka: https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: @user1538301 the docs state it clearly that `HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application`. Thanks for the example though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that by doing this:

```
static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(Network.baseAddress),
    DefaultRequestHeaders =
    {
        Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Network.token)
    }
};
```

Regarding HttpClient as a singleton, it's in general not the best practice(not optimal control of connection lieftime) but it all depends on how you are going to use it. It wouldn't be sensible to keep `HttpClient` in memory forever if your application will not use it very often. The best practice is to use named or typed `HttpClient` or to use `IHttpClientFactory`. Very descriptive info you can find [here](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)